# Creating material library

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a small application (in VB.net) for calculating some mechanical properties of a construction. For that I need a library with some material properties.
I only program as a hobby, so I'm far from familiar with all the possibilities of the language.

I'm limping on a few thoughts:
Creating an array e.g.:

```
Public Shared arrMaterials(,) As String =
        New String(,) {{"S235JR", "210000", "235", "360"},
                       {"S355JR", "210000", "355", "490"},
```

Put my materials in an XML and read the required properties.

However, I wonder if (and how) it is possible to create a library with a custom object with properties.

Is it as simple as:

```
Dim Material0 As New Material
With Material0
    .MaterialName = "S235JR"
    .Young-modulus = "210000"
    .YieldStrength = "235"
    .TensileStrength = "360"
End With
```

Or do I miss something? Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're already thinking to put materials in an XML format, then I'd recommend to plan to deserialize it into a class structure in VB rather than a simple array.  You'll quickly find that the array is bug-prone, as there isn't anything in the type system that forces a column to have a consistent meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The code below demonstrates how to use classes to get the correct XML structure. It also show how to both serialize the data (to an XML file) and how to deserialize the XML (load the data from the XML file).

**Create a new Windows Forms Project**

**Add Reference**: System.Runtime.Serialization

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference**
- Click **Assemblies**
- Check **System.Runtime.Serialization**

**Add Reference**: System.Xml

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference**
- Click **Assemblies**
- Check **System.Xml**

Create two classes that will hold the data. Add a constructor to make it easier to add data.

**Add class**: XmlMaterial

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Class...** (Name: XmlMaterial.vb)
- Click **OK**

**XmlMaterial.vb**

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<DataContract(Name:="Material")>
Public Class XmlMaterial

    <DataMember(Name:="MaterialName")>
    Public Property MaterialName As String

    <DataMember(Name:="TensileStrength")>
    Public Property TensileStrength As Integer

    <DataMember(Name:="YoungModulus")>
    Public Property YoungModulus As Integer

    <DataMember(Name:="YieldStrength")>
    Public Property YieldStrength As Integer


    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal materialName As String, ByVal youngModulus As Integer, ByVal YieldStrength As Integer, ByVal tensilStrength As Integer)
        Me.MaterialName = materialName
        Me.YoungModulus = youngModulus
        Me.YieldStrength = YieldStrength
        Me.TensileStrength = tensilStrength
    End Sub

End Class
```

So that the XML file has the correct structure, create another class that has a list of XmlMaterial. Add a method (AddMaterial) to make it easier to add data.

**Add class**: XmlRoot

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Class...** (Name: XmlRoot.vb)
- Click **OK**

**XmlRoot.vb**

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<DataContract(Name:="Root")>
Public Class XmlRoot

    <DataMember(Name:="Materials")>
    Public Property Materials As New List(Of XmlMaterial)

    Public Sub AddMaterial(ByVal materialName As String, ByVal youngModulus As Integer, ByVal yieldStrength As Integer, ByVal tensilStrength As Integer)
        Materials.Add(New XmlMaterial(materialName, youngModulus, yieldStrength, tensilStrength))
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Add Module**: HelperSerialization

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Module...** (Name: HelperSerialization.vb)
- Click **OK**

The code in "HelperSerialization.vb" is used to write to the XML file (serialize) and to read data from the XML file (deserialize).

**HelperSerialization.vb**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Xml

Module HelperSerialization

    Public Function DeserializeXml(Of T)(ByVal filename As String) As T
        Dim result As T = CType(Nothing, T)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: Filename is null or empty")
            Return result
        End If

        Try
            'create new instance
            Dim mySerializer As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(T))

            'read XML file
            Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
                Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fs)
                    Return mySerializer.ReadObject(reader)
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (DeserializeXml - SerializationException) - " & ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (DeserializeXml) - " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Sub SerializeToXmlFile(ByVal filename As String, ByVal xmlObject As Object)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: Filename is null or empty")
            Return
        End If

        Try
            'create new instance
            Dim mySerializer As New DataContractSerializer(xmlObject.GetType())

            Dim myXmlWriterSettings As New XmlWriterSettings
            With myXmlWriterSettings
                .OmitXmlDeclaration = False
                .Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                .Indent = True
            End With

            'write to XML file
            Using myXmlWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename, myXmlWriterSettings)

                'serialize 
                mySerializer.WriteObject(myXmlWriter, xmlObject)
            End Using

        Catch ex As System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (SerializeToXmlFile - SerializationException) - " & ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (SerializeToXmlFile) - " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**
- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.vb**
- Select **View Designer**

**Add button to form** (name: btnSave)

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Click **Button**
- Click on form to add the button to the form

**Add button to form** (name: btnLoad)

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Click **Button**
- Click on form to add the button to the form

**Note**: Double-click each button to create click handler

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.vb**
- Select **View Code**

**Form1.vb**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private ConstructionMaterials As New XmlRoot
    Private filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "materials.xml")


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        CreateTestData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateTestData()
        ConstructionMaterials.AddMaterial("S235JR", "210000", "235", "360")
        ConstructionMaterials.AddMaterial("S123JR", "200000", "212", "300")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        'serialize - write to file
        SerializeToXmlFile(filename, ConstructionMaterials)

        Debug.WriteLine("Data saved to: " & filename)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

        'deserialize - read from file
        ConstructionMaterials = DeserializeXml(Of XmlRoot)(filename)

        If ConstructionMaterials IsNot Nothing AndAlso ConstructionMaterials.Materials.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Data read from: " & filename)
        End If

        If ConstructionMaterials IsNot Nothing Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To ConstructionMaterials.Materials.Count - 1
                Debug.WriteLine(ConstructionMaterials.Materials(i).MaterialName & " " & ConstructionMaterials.Materials(i).TensileStrength)
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

The code above will create the following XML file.

**materials.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MaterialProject">
  <Materials>
    <Material>
      <MaterialName>S235JR</MaterialName>
      <TensileStrength>360</TensileStrength>
      <YieldStrength>235</YieldStrength>
      <YoungModulus>210000</YoungModulus>
    </Material>
    <Material>
      <MaterialName>S123JR</MaterialName>
      <TensileStrength>300</TensileStrength>
      <YieldStrength>212</YieldStrength>
      <YoungModulus>200000</YoungModulus>
    </Material>
  </Materials>
</Root>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this comprehensive response. I never thought of the possibility of building the XML from within the program as well. I'm going to work on this. Thank you again!